# MFMailComposeViewController customize send button

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uibarbuttonitem, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmailcomposer

I need to be able to change both the background color and the title color for the `UIBarButtonItem` "Send" on the `MFMailComposeViewController`.

Changing the customView property force it no longer to behave.

Sample code:

```
MFMailComposeViewController* vc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
vc.mailComposeDelegate = self;

//This fails:
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:vc animated:TRUE];
self.topViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.customView = 
     [self makeMyView];
```

Also by overriding properties (target,action) to my method. This too is no longer called.

Is there a way to override the customView on this button?

I'm supporting iOS4 otherwise I wouldn't be in this trouble & I don't have the time at the moment to integrate a full SMTP client such as `SKPSMTPMessage`.